# Yii CDbCommand create query

Tags: sql, yii

I can't create the following query using Yii:

```
SELECT recipientId as broadcasterId, SUM(quantity) as quantity FROM `creditlog` 
WHERE websiteId=3 AND timeAdded>='2013-01-17' 
AND timeAdded<='2013-02-17' 
AND recipientId IN (10000024, 10000026, 1000028) GROUP BY `recipientId`
```

I tried:

```
$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand();
$command->select('recipientId as broadcasterId, SUM(quantity) as quantity');
$command->from('creditlog');

$command->where('websiteId=:websiteId AND timeAdded>=:dateStart AND timeAdded<=:dateEnd AND recipientId IN (:recipients)',array(':websiteId' => $websiteId, ':dateStart' => $dateStart, ':dateEnd' => $dateEnd, ':recipients' => $broadcasterIds));

$command->group('recipientId');
```

also the `andWhere()` function which is in the docs seems to be missing.

The issue is that IN condition but I can't find a way to rewrite it.

Comment: [`andWhere` is available since v1.1.13](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#andWhere-detail), maybe your version is older

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you don't have access to `andWhere`, which would make life much simpler, you have to express the parameters with `where` like this:

```
$command->where(array(
    array('and', 
          'websiteId=:websiteId',
          array('and', 
                'timeAdded>=:dateStart',
                 array('and',
                       // ...

), $parameters);
```

This is done so that you can at some point use the proper `array('in', 'recipientId', $values)` syntax to produce the `IN(...)` SQL.

However, this is ugly and difficult to manage. As long as all the conditions are simply joined together with `AND` you can construct the data structure programmatically from a saner data representation like this (in effect this is a workaround for the missing `andWhere`):

```
$conditions = array(
    'websiteId=:websiteId',
    'timeAdded>=:dateStart',
    'timeAdded<=:dateEnd',
    array('in', 'recipientId', $broadcasterIds),

);

$where = null;
foreach ($conditions as $condition) {
    if (!$where) {
        $where = $condition;
    }
    else {
        $where = array('and', $where, $condition);
    }
}

$command->where($where, $parameters);
```

For more information on why this way of expressing things has to be used you can refer to the documentation for [`CDbCommand::where`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#where%28%29-detail).

Comment: Well the getText() is returning: AND (`recipientId` IN (\'5339297,10000023,10000024\')) and I don't think that's right

Comment: @Samson: `$broadcasterIds` is supposed to be an array, this sounds like it's a string.