# How to set multiple condition on criteria for CActiveDataProvider?

Tags: php, yii, criteria

I'm on project of `YII`. I have `Production` table, where I have `category_id` and `brand_id` two column. Now what I want to do is, just use the `CActiveDataProvider` to fetch those particular rows to the `$dataprovider` which has those `category_id` and `brand_id` in my `$cat` and `$brnd` array. I made it for `category_id`, but I am not getting any thing how to put both of them on the condition. Here is my code, please help.

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider(Production::model(),
      array(
     'criteria'=>array('condition' => 'category_id IN ('.implode(',',$cat).')'),
     'pagination' => array('pageSize'=>Yii::app()->params['productsPerPage']),
    )
);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376856/yii-cdbcommand-create-query might be what your looking for

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`addInCondition` of `CDbCriteria`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addInCondition-detail):

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->addInCondition('category_id',$cat,'AND');
$criteria->addInCondition('brand_id',$brnd,'AND');
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider(
    'Production',
    array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
        'pagination' => array('pageSize'=>Yii::app()->params['productsPerPage']),
    )
);
```

The last parameter of `addInCondition` specifies how the condition will be appended to the existing conditions, so if you want

```
category_id IN (x,y,z) AND brand_id IN (a,b,c)
```

i.e `AND` then you don't need to specify the 3rd parameter (default is AND), but if you want `OR`, as in

```
category_id IN (x,y,z) OR brand_id IN (a,b,c)
```

then you need to use

```
$criteria->addInCondition('brand_id',$brnd,'OR');
```

Comment: I think you have given correct answer, just I am getting error for criteria->addInCondition('brand_id',$brnd,'AND');.  
Object of class Brand could not be converted to string (.../framework/db/CDbCommand.php:274) what is the problem in here?

Comment: I am sorry, that was my mistake, that has to be $brans_id